# Trouble with dependent matrix solution

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Im determining the eigenvector for $\lambda = 6$. Here is the following matrix $A - 6*I$:

```
0  0  0  0
0  1  0  1
0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0
```

Thus the corresponding equation: $x_2 = -x_4$

Thus $x_1,x_3,x_4$ are free.

How do I express this in terms of an eigenvector, a little confused..?

Comment: $(x_1,-x_4,x_3,x_4)$

Comment: So, for each free variable, you have an eigenvector.  The eigenspace is three dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler example to show what can happen.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\0&2\end{array}\right]$$

You will get $(2-\lambda)^2 = 0$ to solve for eigenvalues. So two eigenvalues at $2$.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}\right]$$

Wee see that the only requirement is $x_2 = 0$ and $x_1$ can be what it wants. Only one eigenvector!